# React: How to display cropped image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my project, There is a cropper used react-cropper package. But the result "cropData" is in base6 format. Then convert the cropped image from base64 to a file and I want to display that result image in a div.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cropper from "react-cropper";

import { dataUrlToFile } from "./utils";

import "./Demo.css";
import "cropperjs/dist/cropper.css";

type Props = {
  LabelName?: string;
};


export const Demo = (props: Props) => {
  const { LabelName } = props;
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState({});
  const [cropData, setCropData] = useState("#");
  const [cropper, setCropper] = useState<any>();

  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("e value", e);
    let files;
    if (e.dataTransfer) {
      files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    } else if (e.target) {
      files = e.target.files;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      setImage(reader.result as any);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  };

  const getCropData = () => {
    if (typeof cropper !== "undefined") {
      setCropData(cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL());
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = async (url: string) => {
    console.log("url", url);
    const file = dataUrlToFile(url, "output.png");

    console.log(
      `We have File "${file.name}", now we can upload it wherever we want!`
    );
    setFile(file)
  };

  console.log("cropData", cropData);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <input type="file" onChange={onChange} />
        <br />
        <div className="container">
          <Cropper
            style={{
              height: 600,
              width: 800,
              margin: "0 auto",
              marginTop: 25,
            }}
            zoomOnTouch={true}
            zoomOnWheel={true}
            // zoomable={true}
            // zoomTo={0.5}
            aspectRatio={4}
            preview=".img-preview"
            src={image}
            viewMode={3}
            minCropBoxWidth={800}
            minCropBoxHeight={200}
            background={false}
            responsive={true}
            checkOrientation={false}
            onInitialized={(instance) => {
              console.log("instance", instance);
              setCropper(instance);
            }}
            guides={true}
            cropBoxResizable={false}
            dragMode="move"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <br style={{ clear: "both" }} />

      <div
        className="box"
        style={{ width: "50%", float: "right", height: "300px" }}
      >
        <h1>
          <span>Crop</span>
          <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={getCropData}>
            Crop Image
          </button>
        </h1>
        <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={cropData} alt="cropped" />
      </div>
      {cropData && (
        <button
          style={{ float: "right" }}
          onClick={() => handleUpload(cropData)}
        >
          Upload
        </button>
      )}

      <h1>
          Result image
      </h1>
      <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src=*To display image* alt="cropped" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

When console the "file" then it look like this.

[image]

The file is an object so confused about how to call the "src" inside the . Please give me some suggestions to correct this situation.
https://codesandbox.io/s/old-snow-fkw3l?file=/src/Demo.tsx:1240-1253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the file to a dataURL to put it as src in the img tag of html.
You can use the function `readAsDataURL(blob)` for this. See this from MDN docs, [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)